Prevent temp drive being formatted and mounted
When creating a Linux Azure VM with "temp disk" (locally SSD) such as D2ds_v4, the disk is formatted ext4 and already mounted at /mnt via some mechanism.
This is annoying for me because I don't want it formatted ext4, and I certain don't want it mounted at /mnt (which seems like a bug, things should be mounted at a subdirectory of /mnt not at the directory itself).
How can I prevent this so I can format the disk myself?

You can use cloud-init under custom data to modify vm provisioning.check this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/answers/questions/2119256/unwanted-formatting-mounting-of-temp-drive

Is going to a SKU without the local drive an option? E.g. Easv4, Dasv5, Dpsv6, etc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes/general-purpose/dasv5-series?tabs=sizebasic
Or do you really need the temp disk?

@JulianHüppauff - I need the temp disk.

@BeeOnRope you can prevent the temporary disk from being automatically formatted and mounted when creating a Linux Azure VM (e.g., D2ds_v4), you can configure the Azure Linux Agent (waagent) to disable this behavior.

To prevent the temporary disk from being automatically formatted and mounted when creating a Linux Azure VM (e.g. D2ds_v4), you can configure the Azure Linux Agent (waagent) to disable this behavior.
Edit Azure Linux Agent Configuration (waagent.conf)
sudo vim /etc/waagent.conf

Update the following parameters
ResourceDisk.Format=n
ResourceDisk.EnableSwap=n
ResourceDisk.MountPoint=


Apply the changes by restarting the Azure Linux Agent
sudo systemctl restart walinuxagent

If the temporary disk is already formatted and mounted (e.g. at /mnt), unmount it
sudo umount /mnt || true


verify the disk status after that once with lsblk
If the disk has been partitioned (e.g. /dev/sdb1), delete the partition using fdisk
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb


Manually Format and Mount the Disk
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
sudo mkdir -p /mytempdisk
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mytempdisk
echo "/dev/sdb /mytempdisk ext4 defaults 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab


now reboot and check

The temporary disk (/dev/sdb) is mounted at your custom mount point /mytempdisk with the ext4 filesystem. This mount persists across reboots as configured in /etc/fstab. The /etc/waagent.conf changes successfully prevented Azure's automatic formatting and mounting of the temporary disk. The disk is no longer mounted at /mnt or formatted as ext4 automatically by Azure.
If you want to have it during VM creation then add a script in the cloud init section
#cloud-config
disk_setup:
  ephemeral0:
    table_type: mbr
    layout: True
    overwrite: False
fs_setup:
  - label: ephemeral0
    filesystem: ext3
    device: ephemeral0.1
    replace_fs: ntfs
mounts:
  - [ephemeral0, /mnt/resource, auto, "defaults,nofail", "0", "2"]



The waagent.conf method is for manual disk configuration.
The cloud-init script is for automating disk setup during provisioning.
Reference doc-

using-cloud-init-on-azure-vm

custom-data on azure vm


